# Is there any difference in the syntax of Fortran 90 and 95?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Are the syntax and the way Fortran 90 and 95 work, the same? I am new to Fortran and am not well informed about the language. I need to learn it for my project.

Comment: Fortran 95 extends and clarifies Fortran 90, but a valid Fortran 90 program should, with a few very, very, very unimportant exceptions, also be a valid Fortran 95 program. Nowadays you should be using at least Fortran 2003, though. When I have time I will write a proper answer (or find a duplicate)

Comment: When it comes to syntax, there is no difference between Fortran 90 and 95 appart from a few added features like `FORALL` (and deleted some very obsolescent features). Fortran 95 also clarified some problematic semantics (like the allocatable arrays). The linked question may benefit from some clarification and additional answers and anyone is welcome to add an answer there.

Comment: Gfortran and commercial compilers support Fortran 2003 or higher, which includes Fortran 95, so I don't see why one would restrict oneself to Fortran 90.